# OpenGL ES draw Lorentz or other attractors

Tags: opengl-es

I d like to draw something like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WJFyImA3Aw)

How i can draw an attractor in OpenGL ES, and then animate it, how to start this? 
Drawing the points like textures, or how?

Any information on this will be very helpful, thanks